# Handling repeated values in template

Tags: java, forms, scala, playframework-2.1

the documentation says I can use @repeat for lists defined in forms.

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaFormHelpers bottom of the page.

This might be totally stupid question... Can I use something similar for Map?

right now I have a helper class which consist, String key and String value. It works, but I have some logic in template. In my opinion that is not good...

**edit:** more info

suppose I have

```
class Article {
  ...
  Map<String, String> resources;
  ...getters, setters...
}
```

I call view to deal with form

```
return ok(form.render(Form.form(Article.class)));
```

in form.scala.html

```
@for((key, value) <-formArt("resources")) { 
    @key, @value
}
```

gives me error:

```
value map is not a member of play.data.Form.Field
```

which makes complete sence, because it is not map anymore, but formField. There is helper in scala to deal with List, but I have no idea how to make helper to deal with Map.
(if I try anything similar, for example use @repeat helper, gives me same error)

for those who are asking what is in Field.value

```
{value1=key1, value2=key2 ...}
```

Comment: What kind of Map are we talking about?

Comment: Do you want to iterate the Map? Give as some clue :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to iterate the Map you can do that with `@defining()` and `@for()`:

```
public static Map<String, Object> myMap() {
    Map<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    myMap.put("name", "John");
    myMap.put("secondName", "Doe");
    myMap.put("age", 23);
    return myMap;
}
```

view:

```
@defining(Application.myMap()) { myMap =>

    Hello @myMap.get("name") @myMap.get("secondName")!
    <br><br>

    All entries of the map: <br>
    @for(entry <- myMap.entrySet()){
       Field <b>@entry.getKey()</b> has value: @entry.getValue() <br>
    }

}
```

Comment: pretty much this is how you deal with map in scala. I know this, but I'm asking howto deal with Map in forms - more info in my origianl post.